# can not open the navigation drawer of inserted webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview, navigation-drawer

I have inserted the webview in my activity, however the navigation drawer of the inserted webview is not working properly(it keeps on loading whenever i click on it). Everything else is working fine.

[This is the image which i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ne6b.png)

Given below is the XML code in which i have inserted the webview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_education"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_overlay"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context="com.aaryanapps.mdconnect.ui.activity.EducationActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/dashboard_actionbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar">


            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/education_webView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Given below is the java code adding the webview:

```
package com.aaryanapps.mdconnect.ui.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.aaryanapps.mdconnect.R;

public class EducationActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    private WebView _webview;

    private boolean _webview_loaded = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mToolbarTitleText = "Education";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.education_webView);
        _webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        if (!_webview_loaded) {
            updateViews();
        }

    }


    protected void prepareInit() {

        content_view = R.layout.activity_education;
    }

    private void updateViews() {

        if (null == _webview || _webview_loaded) {
            return;
        }

        _webview_loaded = true;

        String desc = "http://www.google.com";
        //General.replaceNull(cad.getlong_description());
        if (URLUtil.isHttpUrl(desc) || URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(desc)) {
            //Load the url in the webview.
            _webview.loadUrl(desc);
            return;
        }

        _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        _webview.loadData(desc,"text/html", "UTF-8");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in another layout and include it on top of the navigation layout include.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_education"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_overlay"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context="com.aaryanapps.mdconnect.ui.activity.EducationActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/dashboard_actionbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar">


            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/education_webView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please be more specific? @vryin and yeah, "Try to put this in another layout" as in, we have to create another layout resource file or just change the Linearlayout to RelativeLayout ?

Comment: What I meant with "try to put this in another layout" means it's your own code, haven't you noticed the similarities? and yes you have to create another layout resource file, because it seems that it's having a conflict with each other.

Comment: can you put the appbarlayout into a coordinator layout?

Comment: i solve this.put _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); before load url in webview